# How to concatenate two or more videos with same width and different height in FFMpeg and to maintain the same aspect ratio?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, command-line-interface, video-processing, mkv

I have five video parts to concat all. Each five videos are in the same width and height. The second part is the hstack of another 2 videos and the third part is the hstack and vstack of another 3 videos. While concat all the five video parts the aspect ratio is not maintaining in the final video. Since I am new to ffmpeg help me to sort out the problem

I have tried with the command in my final with filter complex and to reduce the size I used frame per second.

`"ffmpeg -i 
final.mp4 -vf scale=1280:480 -filter:v fps=fps=30 finalNew.mp4"`

but nothing worked.
Also help me to use hstack with scaling, to maintain the aspect ratio for the second part on below command

> Command: ffmpeg -i vid1.mkv -i vid2.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=-1:480[v0];[0:v][1:v]hstack=inputs=2"vid3.mkv

Images

[second part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8Smq.png)

[third part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qilaJ.png)

[videochunks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ETdQ.png)

I have console the info of my video

`ffmpeg -i part1.mkv -i part2.mkv -i part3.mkv -i part4.mkv -i part5.mkv
ffmpeg version N-94911-g197985c5bf Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190807
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 35.100 / 56. 35.100
  libavcodec     58. 56.101 / 58. 56.101
  libavformat    58. 32.104 / 58. 32.104
  libavdevice    58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavfilter     7. 58.102 /  7. 58.102
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'part1.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.32.104
  Duration: 00:00:44.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 189 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 640x480 [SAR 9:16 DAR 3:4], 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Video
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.56.101 libx264
      DURATION        : 00:00:44.000000000
Input #1, matroska,webm, from 'part2.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.32.104
  Duration: 00:01:22.07, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 113 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 640x240 [SAR 9:16 DAR 3:2], 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.56.101 libx264
      DURATION        : 00:01:22.066000000
Input #2, matroska,webm, from 'part3.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.32.104
  Duration: 00:00:42.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 405 kb/s
    Stream #2:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 640x720 [SAR 9:16 DAR 1:2], 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.56.101 libx264
      DURATION        : 00:00:42.033000000
Input #3, matroska,webm, from 'part4.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.32.104
  Duration: 00:00:21.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 298 kb/s
    Stream #3:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 640x240 [SAR 9:16 DAR 3:2], 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.56.101 libx264
      DURATION        : 00:00:21.000000000
Input #4, matroska,webm, from 'part5.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.32.104
  Duration: 00:00:16.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 169 kb/s
    Stream #4:0(eng): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 640x480 [SAR 9:16 DAR 3:4], 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Video
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.56.101 libx264
      DURATION        : 00:00:16.000000000`

Comment: @Ilogan As you needed the info of my inputs, I have consoled the data above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep the 9:16 SAR of the inputs:

```
ffmpeg -i part1.mkv -i part2.mkv -i part3.mkv -i part4.mkv -i part5.mkv -filter_complex "[0]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:480:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=9/16[0v];[1]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:480:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=9/16[1v];[2]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:480:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=9/16[2v];[3]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:480:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=9/16[3v];[4]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:480:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=9/16[4v];[0v][1v][2v][3v][4v]concat=n=5:v=1:a=0[v]" -map "[v]" output.mp4
```

But your inputs look stretched, so I assume you want a 1:1 SAR:

```
ffmpeg -i part1.mkv -i part2.mkv -i part3.mkv -i part4.mkv -i part5.mkv -filter_complex "[0]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:480:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[0v];[1]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:480:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[1v];[2]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:480:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[2v];[3]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:480:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[3v];[4]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:480:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[4v];[0v][1v][2v][3v][4v]concat=n=5:v=1:a=0[v]" -map "[v]" output.mp4
```

Comment: First I Thank You for helping me to sort out the problem. I have an array of videos, it may be 5 or more than that, I can't predict the array which one has a horizontal stack or vertical stack. But I can set the sar and scale for the horizontal and vertical stack separately. So I am using these commands.. Command :(for %i in (*.wav) do @echo file '%i') > mylist.txt Command: ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy output.mkv for concatenation. But it is not working. I am using your first answer 9:16 sar for the videos. Kindly help me with that and thank you once again.

Comment: I am using your first answer 9:16 sar for the video parts. command: "ffmpeg -i part2_pre.mkv -filter_complex "scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:480:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=9/16" part2.mkv", I don't know what mistake I am doing here I can't get the required output.

Comment: @Aarwil I don't see why you are pre-processing the videos. You should be able to do everything in one command. Filter each video input with scale, pad, setsar before concat. See updated answer.

Comment: @llogan could you show full command that keeps the audio stream as well? thank you

Comment: @Ilogan Thanks I have made the array dynamically and it worked. Thank you once again.

Comment: @iwbabn There is no audio stream present in the inputs shown in the question.

Comment: @Ilogan please help to solve this question too
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58727172/how-to-make-my-video-in-landscape-mode-using-ffmpeg

Comment: Thank you so much dear...I am looking for it from couple of days.