# How to make my video in landscape mode using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, command-line-interface, video-processing, mkv

I have four video chats. Somehow I have managed to cut videos into **pieces**, stored in array then stacked and finally concat the video which is in the youtube link down below. I have used the size in the portrait view is 640*480. But I need to show them in the landscape. Suggest me any ideas.

Landscape view:
https://youtu.be/u8tmL2-CdK0
Portrait view:
https://youtu.be/lO-Q3I9X8OA

These are my inputs

`Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'PA473fbf06ed1f952f95c88b9cf22ed0ba_pre.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : GStreamer matroskamux version 1.8.1.1
    creation_time   : 2019-11-05T06:08:19.000000Z
  Duration: 00:01:05.50, start: 63.041000, bitrate: 30 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, progressive), 360x480, SAR 1:1 DAR 3:4, 15 tbr, 1k tbn, 2k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Video
Input #1, matroska,webm, from 'PA183db0ed986039de3197092103a411eb_pre.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : GStreamer matroskamux version 1.8.1.1
    creation_time   : 2019-11-05T06:07:20.000000Z
  Duration: 00:03:15.14, start: 4.062000, bitrate: 172 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, progressive), 360x480, SAR 1:1 DAR 3:4, 15 fps, 15 tbr, 1k tbn, 2k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Video
Input #2, matroska,webm, from 'PA62a810038cbcc00be21fac43e98f5ee1_pre.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : GStreamer matroskamux version 1.8.1.1
    creation_time   : 2019-11-05T06:07:45.000000Z
  Duration: 00:02:21.71, start: 28.803000, bitrate: 92 kb/s
    Stream #2:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, progressive), 360x480, SAR 1:1 DAR 3:4, 15 tbr, 1k tbn, 2k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Video
Input #3, matroska,webm, from 'PA8fa44ff1ba37ee510a045198bca6f04a_pre.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : GStreamer matroskamux version 1.8.1.1
    creation_time   : 2019-11-05T06:07:48.000000Z
  Duration: 00:01:50.69, start: 32.318000, bitrate: 28 kb/s
    Stream #3:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, progressive), 360x480, SAR 1:1 DAR 3:4, 15 fps, 15 tbr, 1k tbn, 2k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Video`

At first, I change all the video resolution to 640:480 because each video may have different resolution (probability). So I am setting a fixed resolution.

`ffmpeg -i PA8fa44ff1ba37ee510a045198bca6f04a_pre.mkv -vf scale=640:480 PA8fa44ff1ba37ee510a045198bca6f04a.mkv -hide_banner
Input #0, matroska,webm, from PA8fa44ff1ba37ee510a045198bca6f04a_pre.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : GStreamer matroskamux version 1.8.1.1
    creation_time   : 2019-11-05T06:07:48.000000Z
  Duration: 00:01:50.69, start: 32.318000, bitrate: 28 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, progressive), 360x480, SAR 1:1 DAR 3:4, 15 fps, 15 tbr, 1k tbn, 2k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Video
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0000021d72eb3f80] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[libx264 @ 0000021d72b33b40] using SAR=9/16
[libx264 @ 0000021d72b33b40] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0000021d72b33b40] profile High, level 2.2, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0000021d72b33b40] 264 - core 158 r2984 3759fcb - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2019 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=15 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, matroska, to 'PA8fa44ff1ba37ee510a045198bca6f04a.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.32.104
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuvj420p(pc), 640x480 [SAR 9:16 DAR 3:4], q=-1--1, 15 fps, 1k tbn, 15 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Video
      encoder         : Lavc58.56.101 libx264`

Two videos merging command

`ffmpeg 
-i ddb97d85-fc21-4fb4-8062-ca2084a48aeb.mkv 
-i a8665a5f-fb5e-44cb-a072-070fbe07a14f.mkv 
-filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]hstack" 1572934056.mkv`

Three videos merging command

`ffmpeg 
-i 16f90447-c8b6-4077-b3b6-4fb2c07e19b5.mkv 
-i ef501109-0ee9-4924-8de1-65eb796a4a78.mkv 
-i 0b284aa6-4175-472c-aaf6-837412f97f32.mkv 
-filter_complex "[1:v]scale=320:-1[left]; [2:v]scale=320:-1[right]; [left][right]hstack[bottom]; [0:v][bottom]vstack" 1572934058.mkv`

Concat Command

`ffmpeg 
-i 1572934031.mkv -i 1572934056.mkv -i 1572934058.mkv -i 1572934089.mkv -i 1572934155.mkv -i 1572934169.mkv -i 1572934198.mkv -filter_complex "[0]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:480:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,fps=fps=30,setsar=1[0v];[1]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:480:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,fps=fps=30,setsar=1[1v];[2]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:480:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,fps=fps=30,setsar=1[2v];[3]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:480:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,fps=fps=30,setsar=1[3v];[4]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:480:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,fps=fps=30,setsar=1[4v];[5]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:480:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,fps=fps=30,setsar=1[5v];[6]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:480:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,fps=fps=30,setsar=1[6v];[0v][1v][2v][3v][4v][5v][6v]concat=n=7:v=1:a=0[v]" -map "[v]" 4c21f002fa76b148c00cc6fbceaa57ee.mp4`

Answer (score 1):

No need to pre-process. Do it all in one command. Assuming desired output size is 1280x960:

```
ffmpeg \
-i left-1.mkv -i right-1.mkv \
-i topleft-2.mkv -i topright-2.mkv -i bottom-2.mkv \
-filter_complex \
"[0]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:960:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[left1];
 [1]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:960:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[right1];
 [left1][right1]hstack=inputs=2[set1];
 [2]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:480:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[topleft2];
 [3]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:480:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[topright2];
 [4]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:480:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[bottom2];
 [topleft2][topright2][bottom2]xstack=inputs=3:layout=0_0|w0_0|0_h0[set2];
 [set1][set2]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[v]" \
-map "[v]" output.mp4
```

Comment: Due to different input sizes using xstack I got gaps or overlaps occurring on the output video. And also the video is getting too elongated in the output. https://youtu.be/dxMTLesfel4

Comment: @Aarwil What is the output width x height that you want? Can you provide a mockup image of the layout you want?

Comment: @Ilogan I just want a landscape view from this portrait video https://youtu.be/lO-Q3I9X8OA . Any height and width are welcome. It is just for to upload the video on youtube in a landscape mode

Comment: @Aarwil My example did make a landscape view from portrait inputs. Your inputs have a aspect ratio of 3:4. To fit into 16:9 (such as 1280x720, which is what I assume you want), and to preserve the aspect ratios of the inputs to avoid distortion, then cropping or padding must occur. It seems like you do not want padding (as the example does), so would you accept cropping? For crop/pad examples of single videos see [Resizing videos to fit into a specific size](https://superuser.com/a/1136305/110524).

Comment: @Ilogan Sorry for the late replay. Thanks for the answer I got what I need from you.